# Глобальная переменная, заданная с начала выполнения скрипта

Tags: php

У меня имеется один из конфиг-файлов, который подключает *header&footer* файлы и непосредственно сам динамический контент страницы в зависимости от ссылки.

[image: Основной скрипт]

Вот так выглядит сама ссылка (передает какое значение нужно присвоить переменной `$view):

[image: ссылка]

Как можно сделать так, чтобы переменная `$view` была инициализирована с самого начала, но могла меняться потом? Какую функцию можно написать, чтобы сделать подобное?

Comment: Надо использовать суперглобальный массив `$_GET`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо бы проверить, передали ли вообще значение `view`, и если передали, то есть ли оно в списке возможных:

```
$view = isset( $_GET['view']) ? $_GET['view'] : NULL;
if( !in_array( $view, explode(',', 'factories,farms,shops'), TRUE)) {
    // плохое значение view передали
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "<p>Нет такой страницы</p>";
} else {    // $view получила допустимое значение страницы
    $filename = sprintf( '%s.php', $view);
    if( file_exists( $filename)) { // полный порядок
        require_once( $filename);
    } else { // значение допустимое, но файла такого нет почему-то
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        echo "<p>Нет такой страницы</p>";           
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$view=$_GET['view'];
```

только валидируйте её потом, а то всякое бывает 
И меняйте сколько хотите. Только не работайте напрямую с глобальным массивом!